# Manipulating .container of Bootstrap to expand more horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've included bootstrap from CDN, and then my `style.css`. I want to manipulate the width of `.container` class, but I don't want it to be fully get attached to the sides. I have read that if I include my custom `style.css` after the cdn fetch of bootstrap, I can manipulate the bootstrap.

`col-md-12` gives me like this:

```
      [                                                                   ]
```

However, I want to expand it a bit more, but not like `container-fluid`. I just want to expand it horizontally just a little bit on each side. Like this:

```
   [                                                                          ]
```

What is the proper way to achieve this?

---

Edit:

This is what I want
[image]

This is what `col-md-12` gives:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Paulie_D, I added screenshots regarding the problem.

Comment: Images don't explain the problem. The container width is set by medai queres, just change those.

Comment: @makshh's answer solves the problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good approach is to change this values (you can also use **[customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#container-sizes)** provided by Bootstrap).

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solves the problem